# How to get a host name behind a load balancer in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, load-balancing

I have a couple of servers and a load balancer. I want to show a server name which is currently serving the page.

I am using `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"]` and `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"]` but is shows the same data for all servers (load balancer information is shown but not the information about exact server name).

How to get a relevant information?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `System.Environment.MachineName`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `Server.MachineName` does what you are looking for?

Answer (score -1):

```
Page.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"].ToUpper();
```