# Get Server IP Address in Current Request

Tags: asp.net, load-balancing

I have a website deployed on 3 different servers and these are using the load balancer. i want to get the real server IP Address not the load balancer. i am using the code:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("LOCAL_ADDR")
```

Comment: see this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512707/how-to-get-a-host-name-behind-a-load-balancer-in-asp-net?rq=1

Comment: @RabNawaz System.Environment.MachineName from your reference it is storing the server name not the IP.

Answer (score 0):

You may try :

```
System.Net.IPAddress[] adds = 
                   System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName());
```